# Splitting linq code into smaller methods: type definition noise

Tags: c#, linq, refactoring, type-inference

I make extensive use of linq for my calculation code (accounting-related). Because of common 'rule' that method body should not exceed 1 screen, I decided to split my lengthy linq-based method into chunks of smaller methods.

After refactoring, my methods look similar to this one:

```
 private static IEnumerable<((IndexFeeSchedule schedule, IPeriod calculationPeriod) schedule, decimal weightedOer)>
 CalculateWeightedOers(
            ICollection<((IndexFeeSchedule schedule,
                             IPeriod calculationPeriod) schedulePeriod,
                             FiscalYear fiscalYear,
                             decimal aum)> totalAums,
            ICollection<((IndexFeeSchedule schedule,
                          IEnumerable<(Fund fund, IPeriod fiscalYear,
                              IEnumerable<(DateTime effectiveDate, decimal rate)> oers,
                              IEnumerable<(DateTime date, decimal amount)> fundAssets)> assets) scheduleAssets,
                              IPeriod calculationPeriod, Fund fund, FiscalYear fiscalYear, decimal oer, decimal ana)> periodFundAnas) =>
            // Calc weighted oers
                from totalAum in totalAums
                join periodFundAssets in periodFundAnas on totalAum.schedulePeriod equals (
                    periodFundAssets.scheduleAssets.schedule, periodFundAssets.calculationPeriod)
                where periodFundAssets.ana != 0
                let weightedOer = periodFundAssets.ana / totalAum.aum * periodFundAssets.oer
                group weightedOer by totalAum.schedulePeriod
                into scheduleOers
                select (schedule: scheduleOers.Key, weightedOer: scheduleOers.Sum(_ => _));
```

Which looks really bad. The main reason is that, because there is no type inference I have to 'pronounce' all anonymous types resulting from linq queries to C# compiler (both in method parameters and in method return value). As a result method declaration takes more space than its actual implementation!

Question: I am trying to find any options to work around this verbosity problem, other than introduce 10-20 new classes which aren't going to be used anywhere except this method.

Comment: If I were you, I would have just left the query as it was. Not every rule has to be followed all the time, and opinionated rules such as that one, is one of them.

Comment: But it really looks too big and complex. Lots of unused variables in the scope of every query. When error conditions encountered, I have to throw 'business exception' to get out of the code, instead of just returning error from a compact manageble function.

Comment: You can do it the old way I mean to define classes instead of tuples and your method definitions should be as simple as : `private static IEnumerable<TypeA> CalculateWeightedOers(ICollection<TypeB> b, ICollection<TypeC> c)`

Comment: This is the solution I am trying to evade. Another (similar) option is to define type aliases via `using` directive...  `using TypeA = System.ValueTuple<(Model.IndexFeeSchedule schedule,
            CalculationTools.Calendar.IPeriod calculationPeriod),
        CalculationTools.Calendar.FiscalYear,
        decimal>;` (losing tuple member names here)

Comment: Can you show a sample of the query with "unused variables"?